# Azure Data Out exceeding limit too quickly! Not much data is leaving the site

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**Please read full description before marking as duplicate!**

I have been searching for an answer and some persons have had a similar problem, but I have not found a solution. I am currently on a free trial of Windows Azure. As of late, the Data Out has been exceeding its 165MB limit in a short space of time, resulting in the suspension of the site. I have looked at the logs which do not show the the same amount of data out as the Dashboard indicates, and there is no reason that many bytes should leave the website in that amount of time.

Live data is frequently being pushed into the website, which is then stored in Azure storage blobs. A WebJob is being used to pull the data from the blobs and store it in an SQL database. In my research I saw that with paid accounts you incur bandwidth charges whenever a blob is accessed. I am not sure if this is related, but could it be that the data being pulled from the blob is also counted in the data out? If so, how or where can a view the amount of bytes involved in each transfer of the data from blob storage? I would like to know **exactly** what is being counted in the data out? Is it only the data that leaves the websites on my subscription, or is it also the data that leaves any of the services?

I don't want to start paying for the full service and the same problem arises in which the site goes down for a period of time. Therefore I need to know exactly what is causing the data out to exceed its limit so quickly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A blob being accessed will incur two types of charges: data out and REST request transactions. I know you mention having issues with only exceeding data out limits, but this is something you should be aware of. Also in cases where may not incur bandwidth charges you may still incur transaction charges.

Answer (score 2):

Typically I see this when the Website and the storage account are not in the same geo-region.  For instance, if your website is in West US and your storage account is in East US then every time you upload a blob from the website you will be charged bandwidth from the website, and every time you download a blob to the website you will be charged bandwidth from blob storage.

If that isn't your configuration then I would recommend opening a billing support incident at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/ where the MS support team can tell you what you are being billed for.

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned in another answer, data transfer between different services in the same region is free. Please refer to [Data Transfers Pricing Details](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/) for more information.

However, if you still would like to see the ingress/egress metrics for your Azure Storage account, you can enable Azure Storage Analytics. Metrics can give you the bandwidth information. Moreover, if you want to trace every individual operation that you performed against Azure Storage, you can also enable Logs.

For an introduction to Azure Storage Analytics, please refer to [How To Monitor a Storage Account](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/). For details on how this information is stored and how you can access it directly, please refer to [Storage Analytics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh343270.aspx). However, please note that Azure Storage Analytics itself can incur extra cost as documented at [Storage Analytics and Billing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh360997.aspx).